# Disallow whitespace in regular expression .NET

Tags: .net, regex, decimal, whitespace

I am trying to validate numbers having maximum 3 decimal digits.

My regular expression is ^\d+([.,]\d{1,3})?$

I am ignoring cultural differences in language (CultureInvariant property is true), which is why I have added a ',' in the expression.

I tried the following tests:

1. 1000 (Input: correct; result: Passed)
2. 0, (Input: incorrect; result:Failed)
3. 1.111 (Input: correct; result: Passed)
4. **spaces (Input: incorrect; result: Passed)**

Even with ^ and $ signs, it allows the user to enter spaces and does not show my validation error.

What is going wrong?

UPDATE:

Following is my code in aspx file:

```
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBuildingSize" CssClass="textbox" runat="server" 
 ToolTip="in Sq Ft" meta:resourcekey="txtBuildingSizeResource1"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblSqM1" runat="server" CssClass="optionLabel" 
meta:resourcekey="lblSqM1Resource1" Text="square meters"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="strBuildingSizeValidator" 
  ControlToValidate="txtBuildingSize" Display="Dynamic"
  runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^\d+([.,]\d{1,3})?$" 
  meta:resourcekey="strBuildingSizeValidatorResource1" 
  Text="* Max 3 decimals only"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

UPDATE 2:  I tried testing it again. The regular expression is working fine. It doesnt allow the input to be submitted in the form, until I clear the spaces from the textboxes. Now, the only problem is that it does not show the validation error when you try to enter spaces.

Solved: ^\d+([.,]\d{1,3}\ {0,0})?$

(space){0,0} did the trick. The error message shows up.

Comment: That Regex appears valid and should not allow spaces. Are you sure you're firing it in the case of white space input? Debug and check.

Comment: I used single space character. Then I tried holding the spacebar, but in none of the cases it tried to shoot the validation error. I tried using javascript code to disable using the spacebar and it appears to have worked. But I am curious as to why the regular expression (javascript being enabled) still doesn't work.

Comment: So is your issue with CLIENT side JS?

Comment: I am guessing yes. I am not getting appropriate results even if I change my browser to Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Your expression is correct. It seems that your understanding of the *application* of your Regex expression is incorrect.

Comment: this question is about Regex, not form input. Start a new question for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression seems correct. I did following test to check:

### Code:

```
var pattern = @"^\d+([.,]\d{1,3})?$";
var examples = new string[] { "1000", "0", "1.111", "1 1" };
var regEx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

foreach(var ex in examples)
{
    var match = regEx.Match(ex);

    if(match.Success)
        Console.WriteLine("Input: '"+ ex + "'; result: Passed");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Input: '"+ ex + "'; result: Failed");
}
```

### Output:

> Input: '1000'; result: Passed
>
> Input: '0'; result: Passed
>
> Input: '1.111'; result: Passed
>
> Input: '1 1'; result: Failed
>
> Input: ' '; result: Failed

Perhaps there's something else what causes this?

### Update:

I even tested this in a TextChanged event in a WPF TextBox like this:

```
var pattern = @"^\d+([.,]\d{1,3})?$";
var regEx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

SearchTextBox.TextChanged += (o, e) => 
{
    var match = regEx.Match(SearchTextBox.Text);
    SearchTextBox.Background = match.Success ? Green : Red;
}
```

From the moment I type a space the textbox turns red.

Comment: Thank you so much for verifying my expression. I am puzzled as well. I am using ASP.NET (4.0) VB in Visual Studio 2010. My browser is Google Chrome. I also tried using Mozilla Firefox but it still allows spaces.